# Is it possible to develop a game with Lua/Löve and have the source code compiled?

Tags: lua

I've been looking at Lua and Löve for developing simple 2D games. But since Lua is interpreted and I know it can be compiled to some point, but how secure is that to decompiling. Or is there a better way to distribute the game?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can precompile lua using the luac tool in the standard distribution:

```
luac myluafile.lua -o mycompiledluafile.luac
```

To obfusticate the file, use the `-s` option to remove all the debug info.  This won't make you immune to [decompiling](http://luadec.luaforge.net/), but why does that matter?

The `-l` option produces an annotated bytefile, which is really nice for learning how lua works deep down.

The main advantages of compiling are faster loading times and smaller disk space.  However you don't get a performance increase after that - the lua compiler does very little optimisations, even to the point of still including `if(false)` branches and the like.

Comment: Lua bytecodes are not specified to be portable, or even acceptable -- they are considered an implementation detail, not an actual part of the language. In particular, I believe that LuaJit-based runtimes will simply have nothing to do with them.

Comment: http://www.love2d.org/wiki/luac <- Löve wiki on luac'd bytecodes; note the policy about "we don't actually support it" was added by 'Bartbes' himself.